# Not able to log into SQL using SQL Authentication and Windows user id and password

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I have rights to a SQL Server and can log in just fine using SSMS and Windows Authentication.

I'm trying to set up a connection string in my `appsettings.json` file using my Windows domain username and password, but it fails.  I've done this in the past, have been using SQL since version 6.5, but always forget the syntax between uses.

Here is my existing connection string:

`"Server=Server\\Instance;User Id=MyDomain\\MyLogin;Password=MyPassword;Initial Catalog=TheDb;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"`

Comment: `User Id=MyDomain\\MyLogin;Password=MyPassword;` is trying to use Windows/Domain login credentials for an SQL Logon, which doesn't work. When using `System.Data.SqlClient` or `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` you want to use `Integrated Security=true;`, instead of User ID and Password, and it will use the Windows/Domain account under which the current process is executing.

Comment: "using SQL Authentication and Windows user id and password" makes no sense: you are using Windows Authentication, not SQL Authentication, and it doesn't use any username and password supplied. It uses the *already logged-in* Windows user, passing the Kerberos ticket/NTLM hash direct to the server. So to use `MyDomain\MyLogin` user, the app running this code needs to be either logged in as that user, or impersonating it. If you are using IIS you will need to set up a Windows login on SQL Server for the IIS app pool user. You also need `Integrated Security=true`

Comment: Alternatively, you can set up an SQL Authentication login, and give that username and password

Comment: Never assume that just because something isn't normally done some way that it shouldn't be.  Not understanding the justification/reasoning doesn't make one way more right.  That's the difference between education and wisdom.  Here I didn't explain the temporary need because it's not necessary when looking for an answer.

Comment: Huh? I didn't say that it makes no sense because it's not normally done that way. It makes no sense because Windows Authentication simply doesn't use those parameters. The code  you have simply doesn't work. Your options are either Windows or SQL Authentication, at the moment you have neither. Windows Auth will use `Integrated Security=true` and no username or password. SQL Auth will not use `Integrated Security` but will use a username and password. This username is *not* a Windows domain account such as `MyDomain\MyLogin`, it's a SQL Server-only user, such as `sa`.